# How to draw rectangle as user draws on screen in android

Tags: android, touch, drawing, drawrectangle

I want to draw rectangle on the screen as user desires, How can I get the points to draw rectangle from user touch event? I have drawn line using onTouchEvent and paint as below. Like this,drawing lines as user desires I want to draw rectangles, But I could not get the values for this. please help

```
public class SimpleDrawingView extends View {
private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
private Paint drawPaint;
private Path path = new Path();
float pointX;
float pointY;

public SimpleDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();
}

private void setupPaint() {
    // Setup paint with color and stroke styles
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     pointX = event.getX();
     pointY = event.getY();
    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    // Force a view to draw again
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path,drawPaint);

}
```

}

Comment: Hi are you using Canvas ?

Comment: I would like to request you make question clear first of all. You want to draw Rectangle through programming or by rounding your finger on screen ?

Comment: @android_softy I want to draw rectangle by rounding finger on screen. thanks for your support. The below answer solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do in this way

```
public class SimpleDrawingView extends View {
private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
private Paint drawPaint;
float pointX;
float pointY;
float startX;
float startY;

public SimpleDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
setupPaint();
}

private void setupPaint() {
// Setup paint with color and stroke styles
drawPaint = new Paint();
drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
pointX = event.getX();
pointY = event.getY();
// Checks for the event that occurs
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startX = pointX;
        startY = pointY;
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
// Force a view to draw again
postInvalidate();
return true;
}

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 canvas.drawRect(startX, startY, pointX, pointY, drawPaint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
Point2D p1 = null;
Point2D p2 = null;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     pointX = event.getX();
     pointY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            p1 = new Point2D(pointX, pointY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            p2 = new Point2D(pointX, pointY);
            postInvalidate();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(p1!=null && p2!=null) {
        canvas.drawRect(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY(), drawPaint);
        p1=null;
        p2=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done it in another way, I don't which is better. I assigned start points to two float variables when ACTION_DOWN and for width and hight used pointX and pointY, `
      ...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        pointX = event.getX();
        pointY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = pointX;
                startY = pointY;
              ...
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 canvas.drawRect(startX, startY, pointX, pointY, drawPaint);
    }
   ...`

Comment: I showed a sample code. I am delighted that you are able to improve it.